# What type XSS this is and how to prevent it

Tags: javascript, web-applications, xss

Here is the code of example.com that I saved to my computer desktop as index.html:

```
<channel> <title>Comments on: Voor uw organisatie</title> <atom:link href="https://example.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" /> <link>https://example.com</link> <description>PIM: Wie weet wat van mij?</description> <lastBuildDate>Mon, 17 Sep 2018 13:22:52 +0000</lastBuildDate> <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod> <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency> <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.3</generator> </channel>
```

I opened that file in a text editor and changed

```
<generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.3</generator>
```

to

```
<generator>"><img src="x" onerror="alert(document.cookie)"></generator>
```

When I opened the modified HTML file in Firefox I get an alert box with cookies. I know it is XSS, because I am getting that XSS alert in my browser.

My question is why is this happening? Cause I didn't injected this code in a parameter. So how can developer fix this or sanitize this code?

Is there any impact of this?

Comment: XSS attack is when you can inject the code into the page without altering the original source code..... All you did was modify the page and as if you were coding it.

Comment: @epascarello — Most XSS attacks take advantage of server-side security holes and *do* alter the HTML source code.

Answer (score 1):

Given a website run by Alice and visited by Bob, an XSS attack would occur when Mallory (an attacker) caused JavaScript to run in Alice's browser on Bob's website.

Alice editing an HTML document on her computer (even one copied from another website) so it runs JavaScript, and then loading that HTML document in her browser is not performing an XSS attack. She is just running JavaScript on a system she has complete control over.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't XSS, this is broken HTML.  The alert is a false positive.

Comment: I can embed JavaScript with html tags. And getting XSS alert with Cookies. Are you sure this is not XSS?

Comment: @user185823 You're just editing your own file... how could that possibly be an XSS attack?  There's nothing happening here but you editing your own file and getting a direct result of that.

Comment: No. There is a site I dont want to mention but calling it as (example.com) i just replaced WordPress.org to img src="x" onerror="alert(document.cookie)"> and saved as index.html and when opened I got XSS alert with cookies

Comment: @user185823 And your point is?  How does that change the example at all?

Comment: Ok I just read this https://klikki.fi/adv/yahoo.html and I think I have found something similler like this. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @user185823 That's a completely different unrelated not-even-in-the-same-ballpark example.  In that case, an HTML e-mail (i.e., dynamic data from a third party) is being injected into a page (i.e. web-based Yahoo! Mail).

Comment: @user185823 Next time you write a question, include the relevant details.  Don't waste everyone's time.